# JavaScript Text To Number Converter Glitch

Tags: javascript

I have this code to convert text into numbers:

```
var vals= ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"," ",",",".","!","?","/","\\","#","@","=","-","_",":"];
var input = prompt("Input:");
var inn = input.toLowerCase + "";
var ins = inn.split("");
var pswrd = prompt("Password(LowerCase):")
var pin = pswrd.toLowerCase + "";
var pins = pin.split("");
var out = "";
var i;
var mul = Math.floor((Math.random() * 30) + 1);
for(i=0;i<ins.length;i++){
  var num = ins[i]
  var val = vals.indexOf(num)
  var out = out+val*mul+" "
}
var out = out+"ↀ"
for(i=0;i<pins.length;i++){
  var num = pins[i]
  var val = vals.indexOf(num)
  var out = out+val*mul+" "
}
alert('Result:' + out);
```

But for reason this happened when I run it:

Input: Hello

Password: hi

Output: 50 200 130 20 190 80 140 130 360 190 140 -10 140 220 40 170 -10 0 180 40 -10 -10 360 -10 360 -10 130 0 190 80 210 40 360 20 140 30 40 -10 360 -10 ↀ50 200 130 20 190 80 140 130 360 190 140 -10 140 220 40 170 -10 0 180 40 -10 -10 360 -10 360 -10 130 0 190 80 210 40 360 20 140 30 40 -10 360 -10

I have no idea what's going on? Can someone please help...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your desired output for input string `hi`?

Comment: `toLowerCase` should be `toLowerCase()`

Comment: No need to make it a string with `""`, By default you will get `string`. `pswrd.toLowerCase().split("");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your coding ways are awful, javascript deserves better than that

```js
const vals = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789 ,.!?/\\#@=-_:' 

var mul = Math.floor((Math.random() * 30) + 1)
  , inn = (prompt('Input:')).toLowerCase()
  , pin = (prompt('Password(LowerCase):')).toLowerCase()
  ;
var out  = ''

for (let letter of inn)  
  out += `${ vals.indexOf( letter ) * mul} `;

out += 'ↀ'

for (let letter of pin)  
  out += `${ vals.indexOf( letter ) * mul} `;

alert('Result:' + out)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the `toLowerCase` method instead of trying to access it like a property on the object. I suspect you were already getting errors from those lines based on the empty string being concatenated - this made your error disappear, but didn't "fix" your code.

As an aside, you can call multiple methods instead of making a new variable for each step of your data mutation. I'm also not sure why you're calling `indexOf` in the loop when you've already got the current index stored in `i`?

Anyway, I'm not going to refactor the whole codeblock for you...But try this:

```
var vals= ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"," ",",",".","!","?","/","\\","#","@","=","-","_",":"];

var input = prompt("Input:");
var pswrd = prompt("Password(LowerCase):")

var inn = input.toLowerCase().split("");
var pin = pswrd.toLowerCase().split("");

var out = "";
var i;

var mul = Math.floor((Math.random() * 30) + 1);

for(i=0;i<inn.length;i++){
  var num = inn[i]
  var val = vals.indexOf(num)
  var out = out+val*mul+" "
}

var out = out+"ↀ"

for(i=0;i<pin.length;i++){
  var num = pin[i]
  var val = vals.indexOf(num)
  var out = out+val*mul+" "
}

alert('Result:' + out);
```